# Using String arrays to tokenize letters of each entry

Tags: java, arrays, string

I'm trying to tokenize letters of a string *array*, versus the string type.

I used `.split()` for converting a string into an array that consisted of each word in the array, but I'm having trouble finding a similar method to tokenize letters in the array.

I tried looking online for a method or tool to use but I haven't had any luck with regard to string *arrays*. Maybe something similar to substring?

If someone could point me in the right direction it would be appreciated.

Here's what I have:

```
// i variables run through rows and j variables run through each word in the string array. 
// tokens is the string array
for(int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i ++){
    for(int j = 0; j < tokens[i].length; j++)
    ...
}
```

Is there a method with regards to arrays to compute the length of each word within each row of the array?

Comment: Your question only contains requirements - it is not showing any efforts from your side to solve this problem yourself. Please add your attempts to this questions - as this site is not a free "we do your (home)work" service. Beyond that: please turn to the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to learn how/what to ask here. Thanks

Comment: you can do something like that run through the string with a loop, have you tried?

Comment: Sorry for not being so specific. I'm not trying to get people to do my homework because that's counter intuitive to learning code haha. This is how I have it set up so far: //i variables run through rows and j variables run through each word in the string array
        for(int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i ++){
        for(int j = 0; j < tokens[i].length; j++)
        ...
        
                }      I just need something equivalent to .length that would help me calculate the length of the word at the certain point in the array, as .length wouldn't work here because it is an array.

Comment: I don't think there's a quick built-in similar to `String.split(String)`.  The straightforward way to do it is just writing a function `String[] splitWord(String word, int depth)`

Comment: Is that code how you're trying to generate the output, or how you want to use the data later?

Comment: Sorry about all that. that's within a method that solely tokenizes, and I'll use more methods that print and sort them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider `size` is the length you want for each part, you have to substring from a `index` to `index+size` and do this iterating over the string until you reach the end which will be given by the length of string minus the `size`

It's better to use a `List` rather than an `array` because it's easier to add elements, sure you can compute the number of split you'll get, but that's another way

---

*Version using `IntStream` and `Streams` :*

```
String str = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
int size = 2;
List<String> res = IntStream.range(0, str.length() - size + 1)
                            .mapToObj(i -> str.substring(i, i + size))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(res); // [he, el, ll, lo]
```

*Version using basic `for-loop` :*

```
String str = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
int size = 3;
List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < str.length() - size + 1; i++) {
    res.add(str.substring(i, i + size));
}
System.out.println(res); // [hel, ell, llo]
```

Comment: Thank you. So in this general problem area I would need to use an arraylist instead of an array, and use the .add method and .substring. I wasn't sure if there was something _like_ substring that I could use for normal arrays. I'm sorry for not abiding to common etiquette here, but I'm trying my best to learn.

Comment: Sure, with an array you can too, bu List is so easy to use ;) don't forget to accept the answer if it corresponds to your attempts